# HTTP Context is null inside a asp.net core controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.1.1. I have an issue while calling **HttpContext** in my controller. When i want to use **HttpContext** the program returns ***NullReferenceException*** and says ***HttpContext.get*** returns null.

I'm very confused because it's inside a controller. can you help me with potential reasons for that?

**CartController .cs**

```
public class CartController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductServices _productServices;
    private readonly ICartServices _cartServices;

    public CartController(IProductServices productServices, ICartServices cartServices)
    {
        _productServices = productServices;
        _cartServices = cartServices;
        cartServices.Cart = GetCart();
    }

    public RedirectToActionResult AddToCart(int productID, string returnUrl)
    {
        ProductViewModel product = _productServices.GetByID(productID);
        if (product != null)
        {
            _cartServices.AddItem(product, 1);
            SaveCart(_cartServices.Cart);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }

    public RedirectToActionResult RemoveFromCart(int productID, string returnUrl)
    {
        ProductViewModel product = _productServices.GetByID(productID);
        if (product != null)
        {
            _cartServices.RemoveLine(product);
            SaveCart(_cartServices.Cart);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }

    public IActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        return View(new CartIndexViewModel()
        {
            Cart = GetCart(),
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl
        });
    }

    private CartViewModel GetCart()
    {
        return HttpContext.Session.GetJson<CartViewModel>("Cart") ?? new CartViewModel();
    }

    private void SaveCart(CartViewModel cart)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetJson<CartViewModel>("Cart", cart);
    }
}
```

When this line calls: `Cart = GetCart()`, it returns null.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.RegisterStartupServices(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                template: "{category}/Page{page:int}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                template: "Page{page:int}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                template: "{category}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                template: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Product}/{action=List}/{id?}"
                );
        });
    }
}
```

I wrote application dependency injection codes in another assembly and call it from **Sturtup.cs**

**StartupExtensions.cs**

```
public static class StartupExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterStartupServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SportStoreDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("SportStoreDatabase")));

        MapperConfiguration mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
        });

        IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);

        services.AddTransient<IProductServices, ProductServices>();
        services.AddTransient<ICategoryServices, CategoryServices>();
        services.AddTransient<ICartServices, CartServices>();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of your Code where `HttpContext` gets called?

Comment: There is no normal situation where `HttpContext` would be null inside a controller. You'd have to be doing something nonstandard/wrong. As such, we need to see your code, or we can't help you.

Comment: What is `HttpContext.get`?

Comment: @Jay Fridge I add my controller and startup code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call your method `GetCart` inside your constructor :

```
public CartController(IProductServices productServices, ICartServices cartServices)
{
    _productServices = productServices;
    _cartServices = cartServices;
    cartServices.Cart = GetCart();
}`
...
private CartViewModel GetCart()
{
    return HttpContext.Session.GetJson<CartViewModel>("Cart") ?? new CartViewModel();
}
```

but the `HttpContext` property is not yet initialized. You can have a Http context only while processing a request.